# Modeling Multiple Api Calls into 1 object (Data Structures)

Tags: c#, xml, database, data-structures

I am trying to model a complex series of Api Calls that return different information about a single entity `SolarSystem` identified by `SolarSystemID`.  Different Api calls are returning the information about the `SolarSystem` and not all of the information can be obtained in just 1 Api call.

Example Data:

```
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2013-02-10 19:30:31</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="solarSystems" key="solarSystemID" columns="solarSystemID,shipJumps">
      <row solarSystemID="30004995" shipJumps="100"/>
      <row solarSystemID="30001746" shipJumps="3"/>
      <row solarSystemID="30004972" shipJumps="2960"/>
...
```

And:

```
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2013-02-10 19:02:37</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="solarSystems" key="solarSystemID" columns="solarSystemID,shipKills,factionKills,podKills">
      <row solarSystemID="30000750" shipKills="0" factionKills="61" podKills="0"/>
      <row solarSystemID="30034971" shipKills="0" factionKills="113" podKills="0"/>
      <row solarSystemID="30003049" shipKills="0" factionKills="195" podKills="0"/>
...
```

I have several different Api call classes to make the individual Api calls (`JumpsApiRequest`, `KillsApiRequest`, etc).  I am trying to model this data into one `SolarSystems` class that will hold a `Dictionary<int, SolarSystem>` collection of `SolarSystem` objects indexed by their `SolarSystemID`.

The only approach that I can see would be to make `SolarSystems` a `static` class (only 1 instance can exist at a time) and have properties that will return the specific information I ask for if the information is current, or call the corresponding `ApiRequest` to refresh the information if it is not current, then return the fresh information.

Where I am lost is that I am not sure the best way to handle this when the information comes from different Api Calls.  After I make an Api call I could iterate over all the results and update each element of the `SolarSystems` class indexing with the `SolarSystemID` but this seems really inefficient.  The number of SolarSystems is very large.

I am wondering if I can leverage some properties of Linq to turn this into a Database like scenario, or if I would benefit from creating a Database to store all of these values locally?  If a database would be a better approach, what is your recommended solution?

Thanks.

All Api Call classes inherit from the base `ApiRequest` class.  The abstract `ApiRequest` class implements:

```
    public DateTimeOffset TimeRequested { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CachedUntil { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    protected XDocument Results { get; set; }
    protected static string _Host;
    private Uri CombinedUri { get; set; }

    private void CombineUri()
    public virtual void MakeRequest()
    protected virtual void ParseResults()
```

Each subclass has properties corresponding to the results of a particular Api call and implements an overriden `ParseResults` method that extracts from the xml and puts them into the properties.

Comment: Can you show an example of one of those API Call Classes? Do they inherit from SolarSystem?

Comment: How do you know what is the ApiRequest subclass that should handle/parse a specific XML?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders Each subclass implements a single Api call.  It's constructor requires the corresponding parameters for its Api call, and it exposes properties that are specific to the results for that specific call.  The subclasses are responsible for building a list of parameters fed to them, the base class uses the arbitrary list to build the URL, makes the request, and stores the xml.  The subclasses then Parse the XML into their outfacing properties.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, i'm afraid it does! So, you have several ApiRequest subclasses, each one of them has its specific properties that are filled when the abstract class makes the requests. Now, you want to know what would be the best way to persist the ApiRequest subclasses properties after all the requests have been made?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders Essentially I want to create a SolarSystem Map.  I have to call 4-5 different Api calls to get all the aggregate information for all `solarSystemID`s.  I want to know what the best way to aggregate all of the information would be.  Have a `SolarSystem` class that holds all information and have a wrapper `SolarSystems` class that has a dictionary of all `solarSystemID`s and their corresponding `SolarSystem` object? Then how would I refresh the `SolarSystem` objects when the Api calls give out fresh information (they all cache for about an hour).  A static `SolarSystems` class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24291/discussion-between-mt-schneiders-and-fortruce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the following implementation:

- Use a SolarSystems class that holds an instance of every ApiRequest subclass.
- SolarSystems would have the logic to make all the ApiRequest's and aggregate the resulted data in a property `Dictionary<int, SolarSystem>`.
- As each of the ApiRequest subclass has a different expiration time. Create an event on the ApiRequest class that would fire when the cache expires indicating that the data on the SolarSystems instance should be updated.
- SolarSystems class should subscribe to the event on every ApiRequest instance.
- For easily updating the data on the SolarSystems instance, the SolarSystem class could have the similar structure of all the specific properties contained on the ApiRequest's subclasses.

An example:

You would have the ApiRequest subclass `JumpsApiRequest` that would have a property to store the jumps `Dictionary<int, JumpsHelperClass>`. And the SolarSystem class would also have a property of type `JumpsHelperClass`. So when the cache expiration event fires, it would update the current data on the SolarSystems instance in a way that would look like this:

```
//MasterCollection  Dictionary<int, SolarSystem>
foreach (int item in MasterCollection.Keys)
{
    MasterCollection[item].Jumps  = JumpsApiRequestInstance.Jumps[item];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to XML to query the information you need from the results. Link to MSDN information about LINQ to XML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx